# postgres window function - over()

Tags: sql, postgresql

my select query should return total count and  other fields  with  limit and offset .My total count will be 1000, but i will be limiting the result by 5 .My expectation is sql will return total count as 1000 and other 5 distinct id .

Is it possible by over () or any other way . limit should not apply on count!

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, total  OVER (
    count( DISTINCT las.id )
    FROM asset 
    WHERE TRUE AND model = 12 AND l status = 'Done'
    )
WHERE TRUE AND model = 12 AND l status = 'Done'
FROM asset limit 0,10 ;
```

sql not working anyway !

expected result

```
id   count 
1     1000
2     1000
3     1000
4     1000
5     1000
```

total count based on condition and ids based on condition and limit

Comment: Your query is wrong in a way that is not possible to know what is your purpose. Just post a sample of your data and the desired result.

Comment: Please post some sample data, its difficult to clearly understand your requirements

Comment: You need to **first** specify the window function (e.g. `count()`) *then* define the window using the `over()` clause. The manual has a pretty good tutorial for this.

Comment: @horse if you answer it that will be great !! i don't understand the usage properly or post a better tutorial link !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, count(*) total
from asset
where model = 12 and status = 'Done'
group by id
order by id
limit 5
```

Comment: am not getting the actual total , its returning 1   . is there anything specific to postgres

Comment: @zod You didn't say what you want.

Comment: i said what i want in the question itself. am just saying what your answer is giving me now !!